# Index.ejs not displaying data from Firebase real time DB when being routed from app.post("/"). Why?

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning to build web apps using nodeJS, express and Firebase real time DB. The todo-list app is not displaying data from the DB when i am rendering index.ejs from the app.post route (as I add a new task item). When I refresh the rendered page, that's when the data appears. I think something to do with the GET index.ejs render placed inside the onValue method? How can I solve this so that when i add a new task, it displays automatically on the index page without needing to refresh the rendered page?

index.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase, ref, push, onValue, remove } from "firebase/database"; 

import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  databaseURL: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx"
};

const application = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(application);
const taskListInDB = ref(database, "DBName");  

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


app.get("/", (req, res) => {

    onValue(taskListInDB, function(snapshot) {
        
        let taskItem = []

         if (snapshot.exists()) {     
             let taskItemsArr = Object.values(snapshot.val())   
    
             for (let i = 0; i < taskItemsArr.length; i++) {
    
                 taskItem.push(taskItemsArr[i])
                
             }
         } 

         res.render("index.ejs", {
             tasks: taskItem
         })
     })


})

app.post("/", (req, res) => {

    let taskDataInput = req.body["task"]
    push(taskListInDB, taskDataInput)
    res.render("index.ejs")
})

app.listen(PORT, (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

index.ejs:

```
<%- include("partials/header.ejs")  %>
    
    <h2 class="mt-4 mb-4">
        <% let date = new Date() %>
        <% let day = date.getDate() %>
        <% let month = date.toLocaleDateString('default', {month: 'long'}) %>
        <% let dayName = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {weekday: 'long'}) %>
        <%= dayName %>, <%= month %> <%= day %>
    </h2>

    <form action="/" method="POST" class="mb-5">
        <input type="text" name="task" class="form-control task-input" placeholder="New Item">
        <button class="btn btn-primary add-button" type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
       
    <% if (locals.tasks) { %>
        <% tasks.forEach((task) => { %>
            <div class="task-holder mb-2">
                    <div class="checkbox-container">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checktask" name="checktask">
                        <label for="checktask"> <%= task %> </label><br>
                    </div>
            </div>   
        <% }) %>
    <% } else { %>
        <div class="task-container">
            <p> No tasks to show yet... </p>
            
        </div> 
    <% } %>    

<%- include("partials/footer.ejs")  %>
```